# Synchronize microservices with events (RabbitMQ)

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices

We are using a microservice architecture to implement Web-APIs in nodejs. Every service exposes HTTP endpoints so the app / website can interact with it. To synchronize the different databases, we are currently using RabbitMQ. A microservice can publish a message on a fanout exchange and every subscribed microservice receives the message.

There are two problems with this architecture.

1. What if we want to add a second instance of a microservice (for loadbalancing purposes etc.). If the second service would subscribe to the same fanout exchange, the messages would be consumed two times.
2. Either acknowledgments do not work with fanout exchanges, or I'm doing something wrong. When I publish a message on a fanout exchange without subscribers, the messages disappears immediately without being acked.

This leads me to the my question. Is RabbitMQ a good choice for microservice synchronization or should we change our architecture. Here is a short example of how I would like it to work:

1. The user creates a new account
2. The auth-mc inserts the user in its database and publishes a 'user.created' event
3. a1-mc, a2-mc (same mc, just loadbalanced) and b1-mc are subscribers of the exchange. Either a1 or a2, as well as b1 receive the event and insert the user in their respective database
4. The event is only removed from each microservices queue, after its acknowledged

This way I can be sure, that every microservice (loadbalanced or not) receives the message one time. Can such a pattern even be implemented using RabbitMQ?

EDIT: Also looking for good literature about microservices if there are any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use `topic` exchange instead of `fanout` for your purpose. Only one consumer will receive the message instead of all of them. You could route your messages based on `routing_key` params for different consumers. For instance, you have an exchange. You have three different queues bound to this exchange with the same routing key. Your message will be duplicated for each queue! Your consumers from different microservices could read the message separately and do what they need. The message will be not dropped until you acknowledge it, but it's a good practice to push message with TTL.

Comment: This seems to be working as intended, thank you very much!

Comment: There are still some things I'm not sure about. Do you create one channel per microservice or one channel per subscribe / publish? And what do you do with messages that are not acked or are expired? If I just requeue the messages, services might repeatedly get the broken message and run into a deadlock. Should I go with the risk, rollback all changes or maybe requeue the message in a dead-letter-exchange?

Comment: You create one exchange per pub/sub, but a queue per microservice. Your producer push messages into exchange (it's a single point for it), consumers bind its queues to exchange and receive messages from here. How to deal with data loss, race conditions and etc., it relies on the situation. You have different ways how to go round with this, such as building RPC models, lock mechanisms, etc.